# AES256 can not decrypt previous encrypted data after restarting server

Tags: java

Currently, I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve. It's the decryption and encryption of the string using AES256. Everything was working fine until I restarted the server and I couldn't decode the previous data.

I tried saving the salt and IVParameter to decrypt for next time, but it doesn't work.

```java
private static final String SECRET_KEY = "my_key";
private static final byte[] SALT;
private static final SecureRandom random;
private static final IvParameterSpec ivspec;

static {
    random = new SecureRandom();
    SALT = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(SALT);
    byte[] bytesIV = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(bytesIV);
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(bytesIV);
}

public static String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String stringToDecrypt) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is pretty clear that it does not work with random salt. Please show the program where you saved it.

Comment: I've try declare SALT = a string then use SALT.getBytes() but it still can not work

Comment: Same to SALT the IV needs to be the same for enryption and decryption. I don't see that for decryption you load the "old" one.

Comment: @Jame, how about some feedback, two days after I took the time to reproduce your problem and write an answer, helping you to solve your problem? The other people who commented like Michael would certainly deserve a reaction as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SecureRandom` initialises itself differently everytime you instantiate it. I.e., it will also create a different sequence of random values each time. Even if you initialise SALT with a fixed initial value, in the next step you overwrite it again by calling `random.nextBytes(SALT)`. Either don't do that or instantiate `SecureRandom` with a seed, so it creates the same sequence of random numbers every time. But this is kind of counter-productive. Similarly, you also randomise `IvParameterSpec`.

You only need the `nextBytes()` result, if you want to generate new salt or IV values for multiple users or a sequence of distinct encryption/decryption actions. AES being a symmetric cypher, you need to make sure that when decrypting a message, you use the same salt and IV (if any) which were used for encryption. Try this in order to get identical encryption results:

```java
  static {
    random = new SecureRandom();  // not used in this example
    SALT = "I am so salty!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] bytesIV = "my super fancy IV".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesIV, 0, 16));
  }
```

Of course, in the example above I am assuming that actually salt and IV were initially created randomly, then securely saved or transmitted to the recipient, and then loaded/received and used to decrypt the message. In a real-world scenario, you would transmit or store salt and IV asymmetrically encrypted (using public-key cryptography), while the message itself (which usually is much bigger than secret key, salt and IV) is encrypted using the much faster and more efficient symmetric AES256 algorithm.

P.S.: `Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesIV, 0, 16)` is necessary, because in contrast to the salt the IV must be exactly 16 bytes long. The salt is more flexible.

---

**Update:** Actually, it is not necessary to encrypt salt and IV. They just make sure that the same input and secret key do not yield the same encrypted message in order to make attacks based on known cleartext more difficult. This is also why e.g. when storing salted hashes in a database, you store the salt values as cleartext along with the salted password hash (not the password itself!), because you need them every time you want to validate a user password.

Comment: "my super fancy IV".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); returns 17 bytes array.. which does not work in AES/CBC algorithm. but removing a character from the string will do the work exactly. thanks +1